# Is YouTube still using DASH?

Tags: youtube, mpeg-dash

Is YouTube using MPEG-DASH for delivering its videos?

I see that if I use the -F option in youtube-dl for some videos there is no "DASH video", e.g., https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Us-TVg40ExM. So is YouTube maintaining a connection with the server and requesting the "piece" of video by the "range" field of the HTTP request? Or is it downloading fixed-time segments like standardized by DASH?

I cannot obtain the MPD anymore like: [How to get .mpd file for a youtube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43843237/how-to-get-mpd-file-for-a-youtube-video)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, YouTube is still using DASH. It's not available on all videos, on some videos it's only sometimes available. Here's one video where DASH manifest is always available and actually used for most of the higher quality streams (you can see that 720p60, 1080p and 1080p60 are not included in the player response on the page): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AI7ULzgf8RU

YouTube is using both single-segment streams, multiple segments via HTTP Range header, and multiple segments by URL.

Here's an example DASH manifest from YouTube, taken on 18th of April, 2021. Some representations were removed to fit into StackOverflow answer size limit.

```
<MPD schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011 DASH-MPD.xsd" minBufferTime="PT1.500S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-main:2011" type="static" mediaPresentationDuration="PT108.158S">
  <Period>
    <AdaptationSet id="0" mimeType="audio/mp4" subsegmentAlignment="true">
      <Role schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:DASH:role:2011" value="main" />
      <SegmentList startNumber="0" timescale="1000">
        <SegmentTimeline>
          <S d="5016" />
          <S d="5015" />
          <S d="4969" />
          <S d="5016" />
          <S d="5015" />
          <S d="4969" />
          <S d="5016" />
          <S d="5015" />
          <S d="4969" />
          <S d="5016" />
          <S d="5015" />
          <S d="4969" />
          <S d="5016" />
          <S d="5015" />
          <S d="4969" />
          <S d="5016" />
          <S d="5015" />
          <S d="4970" />
          <S d="5015" />
          <S d="5016" />
          <S d="4969" />
          <S d="3158" />
        </SegmentTimeline>
      </SegmentList>
      <Representation id="139" codecs="mp4a.40.5" audioSamplingRate="22050" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="50267">
        <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2" />
        <BaseURL>https://r1---sn-0oqxgoxu-3c2e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback/expire/1618776406/ei/9jx8YM-wDNSjgAfPvaeIBQ/ip/ip_removed/id/008ed42f381ff115/itag/139/source/youtube/requiressl/yes/mh/ZD/mm/31,29/mn/sn-0oqxgoxu-3c2e,sn-jvhnu5g-n8vy/ms/au,rdu/mv/m/mvi/1/pcm2cms/yes/pl/22/initcwndbps/1563750/vprv/1/ratebypass/yes/mime/audio%2Fmp4/otfp/1/gir/yes/clen/645142/lmt/1506791779520808/dur/108.158/mt/1618754439/fvip/5/keepalive/yes/fexp/24001373,24007246/sparams/expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,requiressl,vprv,ratebypass,mime,otfp,gir,clen,lmt,dur/sig/AOq0QJ8wRgIhAPMCUxM1MMLy8KfcHLf7ip7z5Rq4tt6NBspreWJMZYXbAiEAmwrgykyrk4z15eXW-GnmnRwoZ9-VUtXYmnEcTgcL3iQ%3D/lsparams/mh,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pcm2cms,pl,initcwndbps/lsig/AG3C_xAwRQIhAKMOYmNU9KPdWmMNCpYp0ZOOeYqLwrCYH8qQq5afZzoWAiAJRxbgT4hTgwX49wMuWsxnqqMt9Ci0kCBemIlGZGalCQ%3D%3D/</BaseURL>
        <SegmentList>
          <Initialization sourceURL="range/0-593" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/890-31517" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/31518-61296" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/61297-90915" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/90916-120715" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/120716-150552" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/150553-180202" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/180203-210108" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/210109-239915" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/239916-269371" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/269372-299508" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/299509-329218" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/329219-358805" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/358806-388744" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/388745-418705" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/418706-448222" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/448223-478210" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/478211-507886" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/507887-537605" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/537606-567356" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/567357-597121" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/597122-626620" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/626621-645141" />
        </SegmentList>
      </Representation>          
    </AdaptationSet>
    <AdaptationSet id="1" mimeType="audio/webm" subsegmentAlignment="true">
      <Role schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:DASH:role:2011" value="main" />
      <SegmentList startNumber="0" timescale="1000">
        <SegmentTimeline>
          <S d="10001" />
          <S d="10000" />
          <S d="10000" />
          <S d="10000" />
          <S d="10000" />
          <S d="10000" />
          <S d="10000" />
          <S d="10000" />
          <S d="10000" />
          <S d="10000" />
          <S d="8120" />
        </SegmentTimeline>
      </SegmentList>
      <Representation id="251" codecs="opus" audioSamplingRate="48000" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="155958">
        <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2" />
        <BaseURL>https://r1---sn-0oqxgoxu-3c2e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback/expire/1618776406/ei/9jx8YM-wDNSjgAfPvaeIBQ/ip/ip_removed/id/008ed42f381ff115/itag/251/source/youtube/requiressl/yes/mh/ZD/mm/31,29/mn/sn-0oqxgoxu-3c2e,sn-jvhnu5g-n8vy/ms/au,rdu/mv/m/mvi/1/pcm2cms/yes/pl/22/initcwndbps/1563750/vprv/1/ratebypass/yes/mime/audio%2Fwebm/otfp/1/gir/yes/clen/1825061/lmt/1561510679077584/dur/108.121/mt/1618754439/fvip/5/keepalive/yes/fexp/24001373,24007246/sparams/expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,requiressl,vprv,ratebypass,mime,otfp,gir,clen,lmt,dur/sig/AOq0QJ8wRgIhAJctjjGsjxngR2oRG8yAIz5EQ47vTI7A3LQojZBwZhmcAiEApD00wg_Qxtce6R1SQ_IWHs2DclOiGIx2kW8dk6d6Vc0%3D/lsparams/mh,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pcm2cms,pl,initcwndbps/lsig/AG3C_xAwRgIhAI1h8G8TQPeel0t3eHXGF7a4sXVhqmSu8NC2cf3bCBKwAiEAkww0Jk56V7DX2kVZvG8afE23vITPWbLoAT23gcL40tU%3D/</BaseURL>
        <SegmentList>
          <Initialization sourceURL="range/0-258" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/443-172446" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/172447-335158" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/335159-506379" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/506380-679142" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/679143-845242" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/845243-1010225" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/1010226-1175732" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/1175733-1340986" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/1340987-1503930" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/1503931-1666762" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/1666763-1825060" />
        </SegmentList>
      </Representation>
    </AdaptationSet>
    <AdaptationSet id="2" mimeType="video/mp4" subsegmentAlignment="true">
      <Role schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:DASH:role:2011" value="main" />
      <SegmentList startNumber="0" timescale="1000">
        <SegmentTimeline>
          <S d="5067" />
          <S d="5066" />
          <S d="5067" />
          <S d="5067" />
          <S d="5066" />
          <S d="5067" />
          <S d="5067" />
          <S d="5066" />
          <S d="5067" />
          <S d="5067" />
          <S d="5066" />
          <S d="5067" />
          <S d="5067" />
          <S d="5066" />
          <S d="5067" />
          <S d="5067" />
          <S d="5066" />
          <S d="5067" />
          <S d="5067" />
          <S d="5066" />
          <S d="5067" />
          <S d="1650" />
        </SegmentTimeline>
      </SegmentList>
      <Representation id="133" codecs="avc1.4d400c" width="426" height="240" startWithSAP="1" maxPlayoutRate="1" bandwidth="242000" frameRate="30">
        <BaseURL>https://r1---sn-0oqxgoxu-3c2e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback/expire/1618776406/ei/9jx8YM-wDNSjgAfPvaeIBQ/ip/ip_removed/id/008ed42f381ff115/itag/133/source/yt_otf/requiressl/yes/mh/ZD/mm/31,29/mn/sn-0oqxgoxu-3c2e,sn-jvhnu5g-n8vy/ms/au,rdu/mv/m/mvi/1/pcm2cms/yes/pl/22/initcwndbps/1563750/vprv/1/ratebypass/yes/mime/video%2Fmp4/otfp/1/otf/1/lmt/1606324665474260/mt/1618754439/fvip/5/keepalive/yes/fexp/24001373,24007246/sparams/expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,requiressl,vprv,ratebypass,mime,otfp,otf,lmt/sig/AOq0QJ8wRQIgZGkYmOl6AY0rWU8crbzaJYB8vwOA5RqlKIELHfi0xooCIQDSpHhWYBHHmdkh7iShrTzX51lIhLp_z66kSOnJvNo6fA%3D%3D/lsparams/mh,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pcm2cms,pl,initcwndbps/lsig/AG3C_xAwRAIgBmap4vxLSY2HujKjSPPWCNK3V0xnsffJwTAC82Y2BkQCIDQEdgot-9ubhLXO2PsMw1_xQugjN0Wbhq9vj4qVTXz5/</BaseURL>
        <SegmentList>
          <Initialization sourceURL="sq/0" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/1/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/2/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/3/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/4/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/5/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/6/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/7/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/8/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/9/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/10/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/11/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/12/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/13/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/14/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/15/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/16/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/17/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/18/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/19/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/20/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/21/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/22/dur/1.650" />
        </SegmentList>
      </Representation>
      <Representation id="134" codecs="avc1.4d401e" width="640" height="360" startWithSAP="1" maxPlayoutRate="1" bandwidth="477109" frameRate="30">
        <BaseURL>https://r1---sn-0oqxgoxu-3c2e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback/expire/1618776406/ei/9jx8YM-wDNSjgAfPvaeIBQ/ip/ip_removed/id/008ed42f381ff115/itag/134/source/youtube/requiressl/yes/mh/ZD/mm/31,29/mn/sn-0oqxgoxu-3c2e,sn-jvhnu5g-n8vy/ms/au,rdu/mv/m/mvi/1/pcm2cms/yes/pl/22/initcwndbps/1563750/vprv/1/ratebypass/yes/mime/video%2Fmp4/otfp/1/gir/yes/clen/3950862/lmt/1606324910042757/dur/108.066/mt/1618754439/fvip/5/keepalive/yes/fexp/24001373,24007246/sparams/expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,requiressl,vprv,ratebypass,mime,otfp,gir,clen,lmt,dur/sig/AOq0QJ8wRQIhALtSlyS5XVpQiuEuffA20_Jp7lh1Gmi7fw4XO07jrarIAiBhvOVs5tqxprKIv9jRnDbCDikoaIzbykfUIeTVqNhfOg%3D%3D/lsparams/mh,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pcm2cms,pl,initcwndbps/lsig/AG3C_xAwRgIhANGajhD6UnilWxHBUDTeRknFEpXPmwUOodgFiUqI_2qBAiEAuX4eREKdf8T142SN6ivjKTKCPi0vW9VkwfIokkUOn1s%3D/</BaseURL>
        <SegmentList>
          <Initialization sourceURL="range/0-740" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/1037-302188" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/302189-480985" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/480986-660558" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/660559-839437" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/839438-1017489" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/1017490-1195502" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/1195503-1375671" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/1375672-1555198" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/1555199-1732377" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/1732378-1911374" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/1911375-2092285" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/2092286-2271361" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/2271362-2449378" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/2449379-2627853" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/2627854-2807201" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/2807202-2986000" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/2986001-3163937" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/3163938-3347877" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/3347878-3536581" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/3536582-3718365" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/3718366-3900036" />
          <SegmentURL media="range/3900037-3950861" />
        </SegmentList>
      </Representation>
      <Representation id="135" codecs="avc1.4d4014" width="854" height="480" startWithSAP="1" maxPlayoutRate="1" bandwidth="1155000" frameRate="30">
        <BaseURL>https://r1---sn-0oqxgoxu-3c2e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback/expire/1618776406/ei/9jx8YM-wDNSjgAfPvaeIBQ/ip/ip_removed/id/008ed42f381ff115/itag/135/source/yt_otf/requiressl/yes/mh/ZD/mm/31,29/mn/sn-0oqxgoxu-3c2e,sn-jvhnu5g-n8vy/ms/au,rdu/mv/m/mvi/1/pcm2cms/yes/pl/22/initcwndbps/1563750/vprv/1/ratebypass/yes/mime/video%2Fmp4/otfp/1/otf/1/lmt/1606324665474260/mt/1618754439/fvip/5/keepalive/yes/fexp/24001373,24007246/sparams/expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,requiressl,vprv,ratebypass,mime,otfp,otf,lmt/sig/AOq0QJ8wRAIgAp3BYqaGG4m7xhmaYybn1Q2cR6DNlLyGcUF8WGbU074CIH2y7BJpXJNSxln6AykcWyCG_KIP37iPvMWUZCVRrRQd/lsparams/mh,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pcm2cms,pl,initcwndbps/lsig/AG3C_xAwRQIgaF6XOVNFzS00UhPiOtHEhQgAUnwj3U-BGrSsOq37neICIQDYqyps07Sa80OI2RQcOBZv0L8xS9MpomM1d3W7HLWCbA%3D%3D/</BaseURL>
        <SegmentList>
          <Initialization sourceURL="sq/0" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/1/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/2/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/3/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/4/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/5/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/6/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/7/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/8/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/9/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/10/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/11/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/12/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/13/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/14/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/15/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/16/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/17/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/18/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/19/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/20/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/21/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/22/dur/1.650" />
        </SegmentList>
      </Representation>
      <Representation id="136" codecs="avc1.4d4016" width="1280" height="720" startWithSAP="1" maxPlayoutRate="1" bandwidth="2310000" frameRate="30">
        <BaseURL>https://r1---sn-0oqxgoxu-3c2e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback/expire/1618776406/ei/9jx8YM-wDNSjgAfPvaeIBQ/ip/ip_removed/id/008ed42f381ff115/itag/136/source/yt_otf/requiressl/yes/mh/ZD/mm/31,29/mn/sn-0oqxgoxu-3c2e,sn-jvhnu5g-n8vy/ms/au,rdu/mv/m/mvi/1/pcm2cms/yes/pl/22/initcwndbps/1563750/vprv/1/ratebypass/yes/mime/video%2Fmp4/otfp/1/otf/1/lmt/1606324665474260/mt/1618754439/fvip/5/keepalive/yes/fexp/24001373,24007246/sparams/expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,requiressl,vprv,ratebypass,mime,otfp,otf,lmt/sig/AOq0QJ8wRQIgUPvVF_NZVRZI_MgOvgD96KkhDYD1tJFVpPIhVYNOIdgCIQDqdkXksUjNzoj4JoHD86ASeJZfOqYAcrq2bUa_G_q7rA%3D%3D/lsparams/mh,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pcm2cms,pl,initcwndbps/lsig/AG3C_xAwRAIgBZvwzoXmv09nS8lmnZrQhchOV5wpesp4hyc6FqdRjecCIGu-pptjRftT0I8nuWZIKi-wN2jPZpoOGvKfUfp9dxfv/</BaseURL>
        <SegmentList>
          <Initialization sourceURL="sq/0" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/1/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/2/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/3/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/4/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/5/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/6/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/7/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/8/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/9/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/10/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/11/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/12/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/13/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/14/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/15/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/16/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/17/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/18/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/19/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/20/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/21/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/22/dur/1.650" />
        </SegmentList>
      </Representation>
      <Representation id="298" codecs="avc1.4d4016" width="1280" height="720" startWithSAP="1" maxPlayoutRate="1" bandwidth="3465000" frameRate="60">
        <BaseURL>https://r1---sn-0oqxgoxu-3c2e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback/expire/1618776406/ei/9jx8YM-wDNSjgAfPvaeIBQ/ip/ip_removed/id/008ed42f381ff115/itag/298/source/yt_otf/requiressl/yes/mh/ZD/mm/31,29/mn/sn-0oqxgoxu-3c2e,sn-jvhnu5g-n8vy/ms/au,rdu/mv/m/mvi/1/pcm2cms/yes/pl/22/initcwndbps/1563750/vprv/1/ratebypass/yes/mime/video%2Fmp4/otfp/1/otf/1/lmt/1606324665474260/mt/1618754439/fvip/5/keepalive/yes/fexp/24001373,24007246/sparams/expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,requiressl,vprv,ratebypass,mime,otfp,otf,lmt/sig/AOq0QJ8wRAIgEsQ-dxp_w-PeExp75iK_fpm5RbeyWd1yYvpECVEluNoCICdQbNSxVcBwRUbUuDdaTI6I6yfvl68xSM6pkY8NQfAc/lsparams/mh,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pcm2cms,pl,initcwndbps/lsig/AG3C_xAwRQIgUv9SXVhIVw5lf8pmO1lNpWXeIzQ1eZSJkkYOPjdGXJUCIQDpjiV2p0va7mj3yDEAy9Xv3faYg_vYU_f98rj-vbsHxg%3D%3D/</BaseURL>
        <SegmentList>
          <Initialization sourceURL="sq/0" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/1/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/2/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/3/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/4/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/5/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/6/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/7/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/8/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/9/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/10/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/11/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/12/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/13/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/14/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/15/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/16/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/17/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/18/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/19/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/20/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/21/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/22/dur/1.650" />
        </SegmentList>
      </Representation>
      <Representation id="299" codecs="avc1.64001e" width="1920" height="1080" startWithSAP="1" maxPlayoutRate="1" bandwidth="5775000" frameRate="60">
        <BaseURL>https://r1---sn-0oqxgoxu-3c2e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback/expire/1618776406/ei/9jx8YM-wDNSjgAfPvaeIBQ/ip/ip_removed/id/008ed42f381ff115/itag/299/source/yt_otf/requiressl/yes/mh/ZD/mm/31,29/mn/sn-0oqxgoxu-3c2e,sn-jvhnu5g-n8vy/ms/au,rdu/mv/m/mvi/1/pcm2cms/yes/pl/22/initcwndbps/1563750/vprv/1/ratebypass/yes/mime/video%2Fmp4/otfp/1/otf/1/lmt/1606324665474260/mt/1618754439/fvip/5/keepalive/yes/fexp/24001373,24007246/sparams/expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,requiressl,vprv,ratebypass,mime,otfp,otf,lmt/sig/AOq0QJ8wRgIhAIJaI4fwVHVMkDdgjeB34DH3q-HjQETXC-TxriUDZHMsAiEA09uSJGQVvEOASZoejTj1-kumWJ_XUgrxvXTOPTkKou8%3D/lsparams/mh,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pcm2cms,pl,initcwndbps/lsig/AG3C_xAwRQIgVfQQG_i51sj2h35e9kBAc2mGE27puFOo_T53ebqETAICIQCzx8G2TaoWD3n2DLPkUksey8YEBDWhKa_FkcXdZklY9Q%3D%3D/</BaseURL>
        <SegmentList>
          <Initialization sourceURL="sq/0" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/1/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/2/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/3/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/4/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/5/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/6/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/7/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/8/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/9/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/10/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/11/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/12/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/13/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/14/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/15/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/16/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/17/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/18/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/19/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/20/dur/5.066" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/21/dur/5.067" />
          <SegmentURL media="sq/22/dur/1.650" />
        </SegmentList>
      </Representation>
    </AdaptationSet>        
  </Period>
</MPD>
```

Comment: Seems there are no thumbnails in here. I guess they are doing everything manually for thumbtracks. Silly me and I was trying to implement thumbtracks into my video manifests. Not even Google is bothering to do that hah.